# linux fbdev enabling in kernel

Tags: linux, embedded

I will be using ARM based SOC & **fbdev** driver to display graphics on the HDMI monitor,
What all drivers/libraries do i have to configure in my Kernel ?

What i know is :--
X11 & Wayland  is used to show multiple GUI application program on Display device.
Fbdev or KMS/DRM can be used for single application program.

What all **drivers/libraries** do I have to configure in my Kernel, to enable fbdev ?
I will be using HDMI monitor for the display.

Do we have some tutorial or video to understand this fbdev flow ?

Comment: For using Linux, [The Linux Documentation Project](http://tldp.org) has always been a great source of information. [In your case.](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Framebuffer-HOWTO/) Which drivers you need depends on your hardware.

Comment: Link you shared do not say about HDMI.. it do say about VESAfb applicable to VGA... is it possible for HDMI ?

Comment: The naming may be deceiving here. It (usually) doesn't matter how you connect your monitor to the graphics adapter. The drivers are specific for the graphics adapter and (usually) we may assume that it will completly take care of interacting with the physical screen.

Comment: I thing i will have to edit this file '/etc/udev/rules.d" ..to assign /dev/fb0 to Hardware display...